# App Crash when I put Online text in TextView

Tags: android, web, textview

My App crashes when I run this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_biografie);
        setTitle("Biografie");

        try {
            // Create a URL for the desired page
            URL url = new URL("http://xxx.nl/api/biografie.php?dataid=998");

            // Read all the text returned by the server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
                TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.biografieText);
                text.setText(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

**This is my Logcat output:**

> 03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{nl.appone.artistone.reneevanginkel/nl.appone.artistone.reneevanginkel.Biografie}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 03-26 12:35:16.900:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-26 12:35:16.900:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-26 12:35:16.900:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-26 12:35:16.900:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30127): Caused by:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 03-26 12:35:16.900:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:71) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:312)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:307) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:286)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:236) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462) 03-26 12:35:16.900:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   nl.appone.artistone.reneevanginkel.Biografie.onCreate(Biografie.java:30)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 03-26
>   12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>   03-26 12:35:16.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30127):  ... 11 more 03-26
>   12:40:16.960: I/Process(30127): Sending signal. PID: 30127 SIG: 9

What can I do to put the Text from the web into the TextView? It's a PHP script what have an output with a biography.

Thanks in Regard!

Comment: post your logcat error.

Comment: The root cause is the NetworkOnMainThreadException indicating that you are doing network IO (reading from the URL) on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will be a better practice, using asyncronous task

```
AsyncronousTask atask = new AsyncronousTask();          
atask.execute("ur url here");
String res=atask.get();


//Asyncronous taks class goes like

public class AsyncronousTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
String response;
Activity c;
//private ProgressDialog dialog;
//String title,msg;


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    response = "";
    for (String url : urls) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(content));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return response;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code, you will get response in return of this method call then you can set that on textView

public static String HitServerGET(String URL) {

```
    String result = null;

    InputStream is = null;

    StringBuilder sb = null;

    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line = "0";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: i have added another answer with asyncronous task, use that on, just copy that class in ur java file and use it using 
AsyncronousTask atask=new AsyncronousTask();
atask.execute("url here");

Answer (score 0):

In the onPostExecute, you can set the text in your TextView.
I re-use the HitServerGET function of Saad Khokhar

This code can be put in your onCreate.

```
final URL url = new URL("http://xxx.nl/api/biografie.php?dataid=998");
new AsyncTask<String, String, String>()
{
  String text=null;         
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params)
  {
    text = HitServerGET(url)
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String ret)
  {
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.biografieText)).setText(text);
  }
}.execute();
```